# What does 0dp and weight mean?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Came up with this question. Could someone explain this?

**Q.** Suppose a layout file declares a LinearLayout called LL that contains two child Views, View1 and View2. In the layout file View1 is given an android:layout_weight of 2 and a layout_width of 0dp. View 2 is given an android:layout_weight of 3 and a layout_width of 0dp. In this example, which of the following statements must be true?

(a) View 2 takes up 3/5 of LL's width.

(b) View 1 takes up 2/5 of the display's width.

(c) View 2 takes up 2/3 of the display's width.

(d) View 1 takes up 2/3 of LL's width.

According to solutions (a) is correct. could someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Both views have a combined weight total of 5. So View 1 will take up 2/5 of the LL and view 2 will take up 3/5 of the LL. The display width is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. You need to force a zeroed size for the weight to work correctly. Otherwise, you get unexpected results, and Android Studio will even warn you about it

Comment: The views are within a Linear Layout and since there is no info about the Linear Layout's constraints, answers b & c don't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant the ViewGroup width. Yes, the device's width isn't significant

Comment: i dont know why only option (a) is correct